# subscribing to rosout INFO

Tags: ros, rosout, rosconsole, subscribe, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm sure this is a noob question but I looked in the wiki and in here for a long time and I could not find the answer.

Is there any way of creating a node that will subscribe to the INFO level rosout logs? Basically, I would like to do a Python node that will react to an INFO message being sent to rosout.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33503/subscribing-to-rosout-info/) by [Carlitos](https://answers.ros.org/users/2062/carlitos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carlitos](https://answers.ros.org/users/2062/carlitos/) on 2012-05-12**:
Thanks Lorenz, I tried subscribing to rosout_agg before but I cannot get anything out of it. The messages that I want to read are there (I confirmed with rostopic echo rosout_agg) but my subscriber doesn't work. Is there something wrong with this: rospy.Subscriber("rosout_agg", String, callback)?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-05-15**:
Yes. The type String is wrong. rosout's topic type is rosgraph_msgs/Log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nodes send log messages on the topic /rosout. These messages are then received by the `rosout` node and republished on `/rosout_agg`. You can subscribe one of these topics, /rosout_agg should be preferred though because subscribing to /rosout might lead to many socket connections to all the nodes running on your system. Have a look at the message type of /rosout_agg, which is [rosgraph_msgs/Log](http://docs.ros.org/api/rosgraph_msgs/html/msg/Log.html) (UPDATE 20200326 by @130s for clarity). It should contain all the information you need, i.e. the log level and the message.

Please note that info log messages are only published if the logger level of the node that is sending the log message is set to Info or Debug.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5